# Substituting variable for string argument in function call

Tags: r, linear-regression, interaction

I am trying to call a function that expects a string as one of the arguments. However, attempting to substitute a variable containing the string throws an error.

```
library(jtools)

# Fit linear model
fitiris <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width * Species, data = iris)

# Plot interaction effect: works!
interact_plot(fitiris, pred = "Petal.Width", modx = "Species")

# Substitute variable name for string: doesn't work!
predictor <- "Petal.Width"
interact_plot(fitiris, pred = predictor, modx = "Species")

Error in names(modxvals2) <- modx.labels : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{jtools} uses non-standard evaluation so you can specify unquoted column names, e.g.

```r
library(jtools)

fitiris <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width * Species, data = iris)

interact_plot(fitiris, pred = Petal.Width, modx = Species)
```

[image]

...but it's not robustly implemented, so the (common!) case you've run into breaks it. If you really need it to work, you can use `bquote` to restructure the call (with `.(...)` around what you want substituted), and then run it with `eval`:

```r
predictor <- "Petal.Width"
eval(bquote(interact_plot(fitiris, pred = .(predictor), modx = "Species")))
```

[image]

...but this is diving pretty deep into R. A better approach is to make the plot yourself using an ordinary plotting library like {ggplot2}.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it had something to do with NSE. My goal is to wrap interact_plot in a function so I can pass it variables to plot. Is there a tidyverse solution (enquo/!! etc.)? The bquote/eval is Greek to me lol.

Comment: or another workaround would be to use `do.call` like this: `do.call("interact_plot", list(fitiris, pred = predictor, modx = "Species"))`

Comment: @hlinee The rlang equivalent would be `rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::quo(interact_plot(fitiris, pred = !!predictor, modx = "Species")))`, or the equivalent of @G.Grothendieck's clever approach would be `purrr::invoke(interact_plot, list(fitiris, pred = predictor, modx = "Species"))`. Both do almost exactly the same thing as their base counterparts in nearly identical syntax—the extra packages don't save you any pain here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the developer of this package.

A short note: this function has just been moved to a new package, called [`interactions`](https://github.com/jacob-long/interactions), which is in the process of being added to CRAN. If you want to install it before it gets to CRAN (I expect this to happen within the week), you'll need to use this code to download it from Github:

```r
if (!requireNamespace("remotes") {
  install.packages("remotes")
}
remotes::install_github("jacob-long/interactions")
```

In this new version, I've changed the non-standard evaluation to follow the `tidyeval` model. This means it should be more straightforward to write a function that plugs in arguments to `pred`, `modx`, and/or `mod2`.

For example:

```r
library(interactions)

plot_wrapper <- function(my_model, my_pred, my_modx) {
  interact_plot(my_model, pred = !! my_pred, modx = !! my_modx)
}

fiti <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Murder * Illiteracy, data = as.data.frame(state.x77))
plot_wrapper(fiti, my_pred = "Murder", my_modx = "Illiteracy") # Works
pred_var <- "Murder"
modx_var <- "Illiteracy"
plot_wrapper(fiti, my_pred = pred_var, my_modx = modx_var) # Works
```

Or just to give an example of using variables in a loop...

```r
variables <- c("Murder", "Illiteracy")
for (var in variables) {
  print(interact_plot(fiti, pred = !! var, modx = !! (variables[variables != var])))
}
```

Comment: This is a better interface but a dangerous install method. Running a long script from the internet is not safe. We make exceptions for those that have been run by a lot of people without incident (homebrew, bioconductor), but for smaller projects, anything that can't be read and understood quickly poses a security risk, as the user is executing somebody else's arbitrary code. To be fair, there's an element of that in any package, but their structure makes them easier to check. Stick to `remotes::install_github`. [remotes](https://remotes.r-lib.org/) can handle non-CRAN dependencies, too.

Comment: And users shouldn't need to load rlang here. I believe since `!` is a valid operator and thus so is `!!` even outside of tidy eval, you don't even need to reexport it; it'll just get picked up by the internal rlang calls.

Comment: I was under the impression that install-github.me is run by the developers of `remotes`, but to be on the safe side I've changed the example code to use `remotes`.

Comment: Also, thanks for the note about `rlang`! I hadn't considered that the delayed evaluation of the bang-bang meant we wouldn't need `rlang` in the global namespace.

Comment: It doesn't really matter who hosts the script; the issue is that if it's long, it's hard to check out everything to make sure it doesn't do bad things. remotes (formerly part of devtools, and still accessible through it) is by people well established in the R world, and has become the de facto way to install a package from anywhere but CRAN.

Comment: Oh wow, that is long. I think it may include the entire source of `remotes`. Of course, I see exactly what you mean in that most wouldn't notice if they stuck something malicious in the middle of it.